# ABCPDF v9 chainable not working with Gecko

Tags: gecko, abcpdf, abcpdf9

I have ABCPDF version 9 converting an HTML page to a 3 page PDF correctly with MSIE, but the same code truncates after the first page with Gecko. The relevant code is:

```
var pageRef = theDoc.AddImageUrl(uri, true, 1200, true);
while (theDoc.Chainable(pageRef))
{
    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
    pageRef = theDoc.AddImageToChain(pageRef);
}
```

In debug mode, theDoc.Chainable(pageRef) returns true when the rendering engine is MSIE, but false when the rendering engine is Gecko.

Suggestions for correcting this?

Comment: I received the following response from WebSupergoo tech support:

"This is a problem with Gecko 21, which ABCpdf 9 currently uses.  You can reproduce the problem to see that there is only one page by using Print Preview in Firefox 21.  Since the Firefox 26 does not cause the problem, this should be resolved when ABCpdf is eventually updated to use a newer version of Gecko."

I've asked them if there a Gecko-based workaround, or an estimated date to the update of ABCpdf to use a newer version of Gecko; will post a response when I get one.

Comment: This issue is specific to the particular HTML which Eric is using. Changing the HTML is a simpler solution than updating the engine.

Comment: Concur; this is a problem with Firefox 21 + Bootstrap 2.3.2 + very specific HTML. I have not yet determined the pattern that is the problem. Since the bug exists in FireFox 21 Print Preview mode, I'll let this lie until the next ABCpdf release comes out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem, and went looking for the specific HTML that was causing the issue.
In our case it was the fact that the content that spanned several pages was in a [fieldset tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)  We just swapped the fieldset tag for a div tag.